# Prove that it has rational root when $|x_1-x_2|\le 2$ and does not have rational roots when $|x_1-x_2|>2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

[image: task]

Let a polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients take values $\pm1$ at two integer values $x_1, x_2$. Prove that $f(x)$ has no rational roots if $|x_1 - x_2| >2$. If $|x_1 - x_2|≤2$,
then only $(x_1 + x_2)/2$ can be a rational root.
help with task please.
Here are my thoughts:
$(x_{1}-x_{2})\mid f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})$
Let $f(x_1) = 1$ and $f(x_2) = -1$ then
$f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})=2\Rightarrow (x_{1}-x_{2})\mid 2\Rightarrow$ if $|x_{1}-x_{2}|>2$ then $(x_{1}-x_{2})\nmid 2\Rightarrow$ it doesn't have any rational roots
About second part I am unsure.
Can you help please with it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What $x \vdots y$ means?

Comment: x is divisible by y

Comment: That notation is not standard at all, you should edit your question to include the definition.

Comment: what is a standard notation by the way?

Comment: @Daniil $2|4 \implies 2$ divides $4$.

Answer (score 0):

$|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| = 1$

$f(x_1) - f(x_2) = 1$ or  $f(x_1) - f(x_2) = -1$

$|x_1 - x_2| \leq 2$

$x_1 - x_2 \leq -2$ or $x_1 - x_2 \leq 2$ i.e. $x \leq 2$

As you can see the curve crosses the $x$ axis. $f(x)$ attains the value $0$ between $1$ and $-1$.

For $|x_1 - x_2| > 2$, we can see that ...

$x_1 - x_2 > 2$ or $x_1 - x_2 < -2$. The interval $-2 \leq x \leq 2$ is not in the function's *domain*, a necessity, *cogito*, if $f(x) = 0$ at some point in the interval.

Comment: The function is a polynomial, what domain are you talking about?